# Find Facebook friends not on any friend lists

Tags: facebook

That's pretty much the question, How do I get the user's friends who are not on any of the user's friend lists?

This gets me everyone who is on a list:

> SELECT uid, last_name, name, current_location from user WHERE uid IN
>   (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() AND uid2 IN (SELECT uid FROM
>   friendlist_member WHERE flid IN (SELECT flid FROM friendlist WHERE
>   owner=me() AND type = "user_created"))) ORDER BY last_name LIMIT 0,10

But this gets me nothing:

> SELECT uid, last_name, name, current_location from user WHERE uid IN
>   (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me() AND uid2 NOT IN (SELECT uid
>   FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid IN (SELECT flid FROM friendlist
>   WHERE owner=me() AND type = "user_created"))) ORDER BY last_name LIMIT
>   0,10

Seems like whenever I include a clause with "NOT IN (...)", an empty set is returned.

Comment: Can `friendlist_member.uid` be `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

The expression `NOT IN (a, b, ..., n)` returns NULL if any of the values `a, b, ..., n` are NULL. If `uid` can be null try adding an extra condition to the WHERE clause in your inner select to remove the NULL values:

```
SELECT uid
FROM friendlist_member
WHERE flid IN (SELECT flid FROM friendlist WHERE owner=me() AND type = "user_created"
AND uid IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Where do you use this, in the v2.0 social graph?  I need to do it in the graph explorer window.  Any ideas?